# How to make type inference work when generic type can be recursively nested

Tags: typescript, overloading

I've just started working with function overloads.

I have the following function defined with an overload. However, when the function is used, the generic type `T` is not always inferred properly.

```
function arrayWrapper<T>(input: T): T[];
function arrayWrapper<T>(input: T[]): T[];
function arrayWrapper<T>(input: T | T[]): T[] {
    if (input instanceof Array) {
        return input;
    }
    return [input];
}
```

For example, this code

```
function arrayWrapperExample(): string[] {
    return arrayWrapper(['hello']);         // Error here
}
```

produces this inference error:

```
Type 'string[][]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

However, if I explicitly specify the generic type of `promiseWrapper`, the error resolves.

```
function arrayWrapperExample(): string[] {
    return arrayWrapper<string>(['hello']);
}
```

But this is redundant, because the return type has already been specified once, as the return type of the function.

Can the overloads of `arrayWrapper` be declared in such a way that I don't need to specify `string` a second time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first overload that matches your parameters is taken, so just put them in order of priority (from the most specific to the most generic):

```
function arrayWrapper<T>(input: T[]): T[];
function arrayWrapper<T>(input: T): T[];
function arrayWrapper<T>(input: T | T[]): T[] {
    if (input instanceof Array) {
        return input;
    }
    return [input];
}

function arrayWrapperExample(): string[] {
    return arrayWrapper(['hello']);         // Error here
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwE6uQTwOoYA54CmqAPACoB8AFDGHiFAFyJkDaAugJTNvsDcAKFCRYCFOiy5kBYuWq16TFtxYdBw6PCRoMOfEVKUadBj0QAfVVx4dEAbwGIniGMETHFLsAGcoySIRwbgCCEpic9o7O0aiEUCCoSAoMgtEAvlFOsfGJiKzJUPwCGULgmmI6kvrEAKIAHsgAtngANoRUKr6otADmtg4xcQnaYVIyqFSsAOQAFoQtLXBTXHzRawD064g16HCoiHOxxUA)